# On the homomorphism as $M_n(A)$-modules.

Tags: modules, ring-homomorphism, algebras, module-isomorphism

I'm trying to prove that, if $A$ is an Algebra over a field $F$, and $U,V$ are $A-$modules. Then any element in $Hom_{M_n(A)}(U^n, V^n)$ (recall that $U^n, V^n$ is the set of size $n$ vectors as an $M_n(A)$-module) takes the form
$$\tilde{f}(u_1,...,u_n) = (f(u_1),...,f(u_n)),$$
for $(u_1,...,u_n)\in V^n$ and some $f\in Hom_{A}(U,V)$.

My thoughts: Is it true (by straightforward calculations) that $\tilde{f}\in Hom_{M_n(A)}(U^n, V^n)$ (defined as above) for every $f\in Hom_A(U,V)$, but how to prove the converse?

Every element $\varphi\in Hom_{M_n(A)}(U^n, V^n)$ must satisfy that, if $B\in M_n(A)$, then
$$\varphi(Bu) = B\varphi(u),$$
for every $u\in U^n$, equivalently $\varphi\circ B = B \circ \varphi$. Making an analog with matrices on vector spaces, it is true that if a transformation $T$, $TS = ST$ for every $S$, then $T$ is a multiple of identity. Any hint to proceed?

Comment: It is well-known that $M_n(A)$ and $A$ are Morita equivalent. Namely, the functor $U \mapsto U^n$ is an equivalence of categories between $A$-modules and $M_n(A)$-modules. In particular, it is a fully faithful functor (which is essentially what you are asking to show).

Comment: Consider taking $B=E_{ij}$ where $E_{ij}$ is the matrix with $1$ in the $(i,j)$th entry and $0$ everywhere else. What happens when $i=j$, what about when $i\neq j$?